# iphone parse year from 04-30-2006

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I parse the year value from 04-30-2006 as string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this, as @Aditya alludes, is to use an [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSDateFormatter * f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];

NSDate * date = [f dateFromString:@"04-30-2006"];
[f release];
```

Answer (score 1):

NSString* year = [[myDateString componentsSeparatedByString: @"-"] objectAtIndex: 2];

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
NSString *str1=@"Your date";

            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [NSTimeZone resetSystemTimeZone];
            NSTimeZone *gmtZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
            [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmtZone];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];

            NSDate *dateT = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str1];
```

Cheers

Comment: -1 right idea, except your date format string is totally wrong as to be totally unhelpful and misleading.

Comment: of course it can, but the way it currently stands, your answer is wrong and does not answer the question.